# How to search an array for different parameters?

Tags: javascript

As an example an arrangement of countries, as it is possible to search either by country, continent or postal code.

```
arr = [      
{
    id: 1,
    country: 'España',
    continent: 'Europa',
    postal_code: '01'
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    country: 'Brasil',
    continent: 'América del Sur',
    postal_code: '02'
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    country: 'Nueva Zelanda',
    continent: 'Oceanía',
    postal_code: '03'
  }
]

arr.filter((option) => {
  return option.country.toLowerCase().startsWith(myVariable.toLowerCase());
});
```

**my parameter array to search** ['country','continent','postal_code']

How can I search my array, depending on the parameters sent from another array.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but are you trying to search through an array with objects that contain `['country','continent','postal_code']` as the keys?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through each country and see if any of the fields that you are searching match. You can use the `some` function for this.

```js
const fields = ['country','continent','postal_code'];

arr.filter((country) => {
    return fields.some((field) => {
        return country[field].toLowerCase().startsWith(myVariable.toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

You can read it like "filter for all the countries where there is **some** field in my list such that the country's attribute corresponding to that field meets my search criteria."

Answer (score 0):

the [] operator to access object properties dynamically is key here (see https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/#2-square-brackets-property-accessor).

```js
arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        country: 'España',
        continent: 'Europa',
        postal_code: '01'
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        country: 'Brasil',
        continent: 'América del Sur',
        postal_code: '02'
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        country: 'Nueva Zelanda',
        continent: 'Oceanía',
        postal_code: '03'
    }
]
function search(propName, searchTerm) {
    return arr.filter((option) => {
        return option[propName].toLowerCase().startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
    });
}
console.log(search('continent', 'O'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to filter an array containing objects that have certain keys & values.

```js
const myArray = [{ country: 'Brazil' }, { country: 'Canada' }, { country: 'Australia' }];

function filterArrayObjects(arrayToSearch, searchKey, searchValue) {
    return arrayToSearch.filter((object) => {
        // do whatever
        return object[searchKey] === searchValue;
    });
}

const myFilteredArray = filterArrayObjects(myArray, "country", "Brazil");
console.log(myFilteredArray); // expected output: [{ country: "Brazil" }]
```

As an example, what we want to do is use the [`Array.prototype.filter()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to loop through all the objects in the array. Then, for each object, return (*filter*) it if the current object has `searchKey` and it's value is equivalent to `searchValue`.